# where is 'target-executable-hook' defined in AOSP?

Tags: android, makefile, android-source

While analyzing how the Android.mk file actually builds a module, I came across `target-executable-hook` function(or macro) in the `Android.mk` file.

in `/build/core/executable_internal.mk`:

```
$(call target-executable-hook)
```

I have tried to find a definition for this function by searching for `target-executable-hook` with grep:

```
$ cd {BUILD_ROOT}
$ grep -nr target-executable-hook *
executable_internal.mk:15:$(call target-executable-hook)
```

It took a long time to search through the entire AOSP directory but all it never gave me a hint about the file which contains the definition of the `target-executable-hook` function.

This is android 5.1.1

If any of you know where this function is actually defined, I would appreciate your help.

---

**Update**

The source package that I have is made by a third party, and the whole source code was zipped. I can just start building after extracting. no `repo` command needed.

A possibility could be that this source code has been modified from the pure AOSP and one of the modifications is to add `target-executable-hook` function.
I'm not sure about it but from the comment, one user shared the fact that he did not find any function named `target-executable-hook`.

If you come across this function, I would appreciate if you could share any info here.

Comment: it is maybe relevant to add the android version you are using! -> I tried your grep call on 4.2.2 and got 0 results. On 6.0 I get the same result.

Comment: @IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII the android version is 5.1.1

Comment: it appears to be a user extension point, similarly to `base-rules-hook` (documented at the start of `build/core/base_rules.mk`) but specific to executable modules.  in fact it seems that several module types have such extension points (there's also calls to `host-executable-hook`, `target-shared-library-hook` & `host-shared-library-hook`, likewise undefined)